# One page website titles and footers

Tags: html, css

I'm making a one page website and it's fine at the moment, except now I'm trying to put a title on each page, and then a footer on the bottom page. My code as it is has a title on the top page so that works fine, so I thought if I basically copy and paste the code then the next page down will have a title. But this isn't the case, the title is fixed to the top page, so basically the top page has two titles overlapping each other. Hopefully the snippet can illustrate it better

```css
/* General Styles */

* {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
/* Header Styles */

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 130px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header ul,
footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
header ul li,
footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
/* Wrapper Styles */

div.wrapper {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
}
div.left,
div.right {
  margin: 30px 30px;
  width: 45%;
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
}
.top,
.mid,
.bot {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
.top {
  background-color: orange;
}
.mid {
  background-color: blue;
}
.bot {
  background-color: green;
}
/* Styling items inside each div */

div.left,
div.right {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 3%;
}
div.upperLeft,
div.lowerLeft,
div.upperRight,
div.lowerRight {
  margin: 5% auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <header>
      <h1>Example Title</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">
        <h1>Left</h1>
        <p>
          Some text with no meaning
        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h1>Right</h1>
        <p>Some text with no meaning</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mid">
    <header>
      <h1>Page two title</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="upperLeft">
        <h2>Upper Left</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="lowerLeft">
        <h2>Lower Left</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="upperRight">
        <h2>Upper Right</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="lowerRight">
        <h2>Lower Right</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bot">
    <h2>Bottom</h2>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each header absolute relative to its parent - so, add `position:relative` to the parent elements

```css
/* General Styles */
* {
 margin: 0;
 color: white;
}

a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

* {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

html,body {
 min-height: 100%;
}

/* Header Styles */
header {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0; top: 0;
 align-items: center;
 height: 130px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

header ul, footer ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

header ul li, footer ul li {
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 30px;
}

/* Wrapper Styles */
div.wrapper {
 left: 0; right: 0;
 display: flex;
 
}

div.left, div.right {
 margin: 30px 30px;
 width: 45%;
 flex: 1;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 text-align: center;
 
}


.top, .mid, .bot {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  position:relative;
  
}

.top {
  background-color: orange;
}
.mid {
  background-color: blue;
}
.bot {
  background-color: green;
}


/* Styling items inside each div */
div.left, div.right {
 width: 40%;
 margin: 0 3%;

}

div.upperLeft, div.lowerLeft, div.upperRight, div.lowerRight {
 margin: 5% auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div class="top">
 <header>
  <h1>Example Title</h1>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
 </header> 
 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
   <h1>Left</h1>
   <p>
    Some text with no meaning
   </p>
 
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <h1>Right</h1>
         <p>Some text with no meaning</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="mid">
 <header>
  <h1>Page two title</h1>
 </header>
 <div class="left">
  <div class="upperLeft">
   <h2>Upper Left</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="lowerLeft">
   <h2>Lower Left</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="upperRight">
   <h2>Upper Right</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="lowerRight">
   <h2>Lower Right</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="bot">
 <h2>Bottom</h2>
 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```